# The method "clearGridData" does not clear the paging toolbar

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using the method "clearGridData" of "jqGrid 3.8 " to clear all data, but not clearing the "Navigation layer".

```
$("#MyGrid").jqGrid("clearGridData", true);
```

Thoroughly clean the grid, but leaves the "Navigation layer":

[image]

**update**

change "paging toolbar" by "Navigation layer"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `$("#MyGrid").jqGrid("clearGridData", true).trigger("reloadGrid");`

Comment: '.trigger("reloadGrid")' re-run the query and load again with the last query.

Comment: Yes, if you need clear grid too (not only data) you need set URL to null and reload.

Answer (score 3):

The `rowNum` parameter is not **the part of data** sent to the server or filled manually. If you show the empty grid having no data the user are able to switch the value of `rowNum` any time.

If you need to reset the `rowNum` parameter you can use

```
$("#MyGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {rowNum:10});
```

together with the call `$("#MyGrid").jqGrid("clearGridData", true);`

Comment: I need it is only the title bar, as when running a query and no results.

Comment: @andres descalzo: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean grib caption (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_it_works) under the title bar? It contain fixed information which not depend on the data. Probably you need to append your question with more information.

Comment: ok, what I meant to say is "Navigation layer", that is the bar that I would need to hide when I clean the grid.

Comment: @andres descalzo: Sorry, but the existence of the pager or navigation lager is a part of your grid definition. Either you need it or not. If you use the corresponding parameters, then the navigation lager exist. So the empty jqGrid has it and the grid after the `clearGridData` call will have it too. Could you write **why** you find that the grid should not have it? **Which** information from the navigation lager is about your old data which are already deleted? By the way you can use other methods like `GridUnload` or `GridDestroy` to remove more information about jqGrid.